# algorithm for the search of the highest peaks points

Tags: algorithm, max, point

Let me explain quickly what I intend to do:
I have this type of chart, and of course all the points to build it:
[image: Standard LineChart point]
I would take the 3 highest peaks of the graph, namely these:
[image: Right point]
The algorithm that I implemented when taking these points but they are not the exact ...
[image: wrong point]
as it might be the exact algorithm?

Thanks in advance to those who will help me

Comment: Your algorithm seems to take the three highest points instead of the three *locally* highest peaks. Try to add a condition that filters the points and leaves only points that are [local maximum points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Definition) (meaning, the point before and the point after them are lower). Then run your algorithm the way you implemented it.

Comment: Is there any limitation on how close to each other those peaks may be? Imagine that in the second picture the point in the middle red circle would be slightly below the point in the left red circle. Would you then still want to return the left and right point?

Comment: ... No I would like to return the points visually higher after that there was a rush (high-low).

Answer (score 0):

let's say the n points are stored in an array `a`. have a second array `b`  of size 3 with all entries initialized to 0. start scanning the array. As soon as a[i] < a[i-1], find the min(a[i-1], a[b[0]], a[b[1]], a[b[2]]); if the min is not a[i-1], then it will be a[b[j]] for j = 0, 1 or 2; then set in b[j] = i-1. At the end of the loop on all point, b[0], b[1] and b[3] should be the indices of the points which are the three local maximums.